# How to build a Scala sequence of tuples from two sequences of tuples?

Tags: scala, tuples, sequence

I have two sequences of tuples:

```
val seqA: Seq[(String, Long)] = Seq(("0", 123), ("1", 10))
val seqB: Seq[(String, Long)] = Seq(("0", 50), ("1", 75))
```

I need to obtain a new sequence by comparing the value of Long parameters by tuples. The comparison criterion is: if the integer of `seqB` is strictly greater than the integer of `seqA` then only the integer of `seqB` is retained. The comparison algorithm must perform the following task:

For `"0"`, `123` is strictly greater than `50` so we keep `123`.
On the other hand, for the value `"1"`, `10` is less than `50` so we eliminate the value.

The desired result is the following:

```
val result: Seq[(String, Long)] = Seq(("0", 123))
```

Any help or any ideas?

Comment: Your description is unclear (e.g., why you are comparing 123 and 10 to the _same_ value from the other sequence?). Perhaps, it would be easier to express what you are looking for if you showed the code that you have written and focus on describing a specific problem you need help with.

Answer (score 0):

You description is different from the example. You said that you need to leave only greater elements from seqB, but in your example you left only elements from seqA. The solution below is based on the example and gives the result `List(("0", 123)). I hope it will help you.

```scala
val seqA: Seq[(String, Long)] = Seq(("0", 123), ("1", 10))
val seqB: Seq[(String, Long)] = Seq(("0", 50), ("1", 75))
seqA.lazyZip(seqB).flatMap {
    case ((aKey, aValue), (bKey, bValue)) if aKey == bKey =>
      if (aValue > bValue) {
        Some((aKey, aValue))
      } else {
        None
      }
    case _ =>
      None // keys don't match, I suppose we need to eliminate element too
  }
```

Otherwise it can be solved with Map, then you will fix the problem with different keys.

```scala
val seqA: Seq[(String, Long)] = Seq(("0", 123), ("1", 10))
val seqB: Seq[(String, Long)] = Seq(("0", 50), ("1", 75))
val seqBMap = seqB.toMap
seqA.filter {
  case (aKey, aValue) => seqBMap.get(aKey).exists(_ < aValue)
}
```